# Footer option is missing in Customiser

Tags: plugins, widgets, headers, footer

Below is my dashboard screenshot, I **don't see the footer** option in my customizer. I have struggled a lot to research on this but no luck.

Can anybody please help me with this? how can I show the footer option in my customizer so that I can edit my footer, also I am not able to edit my footer because of this.

[image]

Comment: Not all themes have Customizer sections for the footer. Have you checked your theme's documentation or support channels?

Comment: I have changed the theme itself, now I am getting footer option